# Javascript Fees calculate

Tags: javascript

I want to make Stripe.com fee calculator by Javascript.
Stripe fee: 2.9% + 30¢

I made that: the value we want is (result),
Price is (num1),
30 cent is (num2),
%2.9 is (num3),

Please check the code below what is wrong with it?
Please help.

```js
function multiplyBy() {
    num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
    num2 = 0.3;
    num3 = 0.971;

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 + num2 / num3
}
```

```html
<form>
  Value : <input type="text" id="firstNumber" /><br>
  <input type="button" onClick="multiplyBy()" Value="GO" />
</form>
<p>The Result is : <br>
<span id = "result"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Your question us unclear. But, `num1` is a string. So you probably want to use `parseFloat(num1)` in the calulation. Otherwise it will concatenate the string.

Comment: I made that: the value we want is (result), Price is (num1), 30 cent is (num2), %2.9 is (num3),

Comment: Please provide a clear formula for the calculation. `2.9%` of what exactly? Why are dividing `0.3/0.971` and adding the quotient to the input's value?

Comment: What is it you are trying to calculate? Whatever it is I suggest that you work out by hand what the answer should be for a price of 1 and then see if the answer is what you would get from your calculation (having made the adjustment mentioned above).

Answer (score 1):

Here `num1` is string and can't adding or dividing with number value, at first you should change type of `num1` to number by this code `parseFloat(num1)`.

try this way:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = parseFloat(num1) + num2 / num3
```

Comment: check priority of operation

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the edit button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation

Comment: @TamirKlein Thanks for your guidance

Answer (score 0):

To make it more clear to yourself and people reading your code, you should consider using variables for the magic numbers. The first problem is the fee should be calculated with `input * 2.9% + $0.30`. This is because Stripe doesn't charge a percentage on it's static portion of the fee. The other problem is not parsing the input string to a number. Use `parseFloat` to solve the issue. I also check if the value is `NaN` to protect against some invalid inputs.

```js
const priceInput = document.getElementById('price');
const output = document.getElementById('output');
const stripeDynamic = 0.029; // stripe takes 2.9% of total txn
const stripeStatic = 0.3; // plus stripe takes 30 cents

priceInput.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  const {
    value
  } = event.target;
  const fee = parseFloat(value) * stripeDynamic + stripeStatic;
  const roundedFee = (Math.round(fee * Math.pow(10, 2)) / Math.pow(10, 2)).toFixed(2);
  const roundedInput = (Math.round(value * Math.pow(10, 2)) / Math.pow(10, 2)).toFixed(2);
  
  if (!isNaN(roundedFee) && !isNaN(roundedInput))
    output.innerHTML = `Steve bought a dress on your site that was sold for $${roundedInput}. After Stripe takes their cut of $${roundedFee} you're left with $${roundedInput - roundedFee} to go to web design!`
})
```

```html
<input id="price" />
<p id="output" />
```

Comment: Ah, but is the question what would be a fee from a total sale of X (i.e. fee taken from the total price the customer pays)?

Comment: @user2771365 hmm i'm not 100% on what your comment means, but I put a bit more flavour into my answer, thanks!

Comment: @SvenWritesCode How can I contact you ?

Comment: All I was saying is that we don't actually know what question is being asked and, therefore what calculation to use - is it a) what is the fee due to 'strike' on something that costs strike $x (i.e. what the customer would pay) or, b) what is strikes fee from a total sale of $x (i.e. what does strike get if the customer pays $x).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution, but this one allows zero or empty input, so you should validate input value.

```js
function multiplyBy() {
    num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
    num2 = 0.3;
    num3 = 0.029;

    document.getElementById("result").innerText = Math.round((num1 * num3 + num2) * 100) / 100;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Value : <input type="text" id="firstNumber" /><br>
  <input type="button" onClick="multiplyBy()" Value="GO" />
</form>
<p>The Result is : <br>
<span id = "result"></span>
</p>
```